# How to bring specific data from firestore to a textView in android kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to bring user data from Firestore to a TextView. However, when the activity starts, the textView hard string disappears and doesn't display anything. The field  is within the collection "Generales." Its name is "Nombre." Please help me out.

Here's the behavior:

[image]

My snipped code:

```
class idcheck1 : AppCompatActivity() {
companion object {

    internal const val CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 1
    internal const val CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 2

}

private lateinit var binding: ActivityIdcheckBinding
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityIdcheckBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

   // val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val usersRef = rootRef.collection("Usuarios").document("Info")
        .collection("Generales")
    val uidRef = usersRef.document(uid)
    uidRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        if (document != null) {
            binding.usuario.text = document.getString("Nombre")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
    }
```

layout

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hola,"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="30.0sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usuario"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="usuario"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="30.0sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: example from firebase]
[image: the field location]

build.graddle - app level.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.2.1'
```

Comment: 1) Can you edit your question to also show a screenshot of the UID document that you're trying to show the `Nombre` field from? 2) When you set a breakpoint inside the success and failure listeners and run in a debugger, does it reach those breakpoints? If so, what is the first line after the breakpoint that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Done, I uploaded the screenshot @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I also asked about running the code in a debugger. Can you answer that too or, if you hadn't done so before, run the code in a debugger now as I described?

Comment: I don't see any error logs in the logcat for firebase if this is what you mean. It's too long to paste it here unless you want a specific line.

Comment: The code and screenshots look fine, so the problem is probably elsewhere. You will need to debug the code to figure out what that is. Hence: when you set a breakpoint inside the success and failure listeners and run in a debugger, does it reach those breakpoints? If so, what is the first line after the breakpoint that doesn't do what you expect it to do? --- If this is new for you, I recommend starting with https://developer.android.com/studio/debug and https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-debugging-with-breakpoints#0

Comment: So I set a breakpoint that wraps my snipped code and I get this weird error message: Would that be the cause?
Expecting ')'; looking at ERROR_ELEMENT '(1,12) in /fragment.kt

Comment: onCreate:38, idcheck1 (com.example.myapplication)
performCreate:7327, Activity (android.app)
performCreate:7318, Activity (android.app)
callActivityOnCreate:1271, Instrumentation (android.app)
performLaunchActivity:3096, ActivityThread (android.app)
handleLaunchActivity:3259, ActivityThread (android.app)
execute:78, LaunchActivityItem (android.app.servertransaction)
executeCallbacks:108, TransactionExecutor (android.app.servertransaction)
execute:68, TransactionExecutor (android.app.servertransaction)
handleMessage:1950, ActivityThread$H (android.app)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Please show us the layout file as well.

Comment: If you try to use `Log.d(TAG, document.getString("Nombre"))` are you getting something printed out in the logcat?